# Determining whether a number is prime or not

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops, primality-test

I know it's been discussed many times; I've read it, but somehow I can't get it.
I want to write a program that determines if the entered number is prime or not.

One of the implementations I found somewhere on the Internet:

```
from math import *

def main():
    n = abs(input("Enter a number: "))
    i = 2
    msg = 'is a prime number.'
    while i <= sqrt(n):
        if n % i == 0:
            msg = 'is not a prime number.'
        i = i + 1
    print n, msg


main()
```

A couple of questions here:

- In the above, what is `i`, and why does it have a starting value of `2`?
- What does `i = i + 1` do in this program?
- How does the interpreter know when to print `'is a prime number.'` even though it is out of the body loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A prime number is a number that's only divisible by 1 and itself. The method it's using is to try dividing your candidate number `n` by every other number from 2 up to itself; however if any number `i` is a divisor of your number `n` then so is `n / i` and at least one of them is less than or equal to `sqrt(n)` therefore we need only test up to `sqrt(n)` inclusive. In practice we need only test the divisors that are actually prime themselves but since we don't have a list of primes to hand we'll test every one.

> what in the above `i` is? and why it got a 2 starting value?

`i` is the potential factor of `n` we're testing. It starts with 2 because we don't care if 1 divides `n` (and trivially it will) because the prime definition allows / expects that.

> what is the i = i + 1 statement, in this concrete example for? Can't see its use in the program.

It's incrementing the `i` value at the end of the loop defined by the `while i <= sqrt(n)`; it means we advance `i` to test the next candidate divisor of `n`.

> and finally, how python knows when to print 'is a prime number.' although it is out of the body loop?

We initialise `msg` to "is a prime number" and if we find any divisor then we change it to "is not a prime number" inside the loop. If the loop doesn't find a divisor, or if the loop never runs, we'll use the initial value we set which is "is a prime number". Incidentally you could `break` out of the loop when you find a divisor; there's no point carrying on the test after that.

As another aside you probably want to compute `sqrt(n)` outside the while and store than in a variable to use in the `while` - you may be recalculating the square root for every iteration, which is relatively expensive.

Comment: much obliged for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've added comments on the sides to explain what each line does:

```
from math import * # imports everything from the math module

def main():
    n = abs(input("Enter a number: ")) # gets input from the user
    i = 2 # starts off at 2 because all input is divisble by 1
    msg = 'is a prime number.' # the message is initially set
    while i <= sqrt(n):
        if n % i == 0: # if 'i' divides evenly into n
            msg = 'is not a prime number.' # only set if it isn't a prime
        i = i + 1 # increases 'i' by 1 so it can check every value up to the square-root of 'n' (to see if it divides evenly)
    print n, msg


main()
```

The program has to go through every value of `i` (up to the square-root of `n`) so that every possible factor is checked.

This is sort of a rough-prime checker, and inefficient for large numbers that aren't prime:
If the input was a number like `1234567890`, it will iterate through every number up to the square root of that number, which is `35147` (rounded up).
Using `return` statements break the loop, so the first number you check, `2`, it is declared not prime since it is evenly divisible by `2`.
By using `return`, it will stop the function, and save you 35,146 calculations. That isn't a massive number (for computers, at least) but it's still more memory-efficient and takes less time.

```
def isPrime(n):
    '''Checks if 'n' is prime.'''
    from math import sqrt
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return False
    else:
        for check in range(2, int(sqrt(n))+1):
            if n % check == 0: return False
    return True
```

Comment: Sidenote: why import sqrt if you don't use it? ;)

Comment: Woops, I forgot to add that part in :P